# Initialize array of non-copyable non-movable objects in another objects constructor

Tags: c++, initializer-list, systemc

This question pertains to both array initialization and SystemC module hierarchies.

I have a class that is non-copyable, non-movable, and no default constructor:

```
class Object : public sc_module {
    public:
      Object(string name, Configuration config);
      Object(const CPU& that) = delete;

};
```

and another class that has an array of these:

```
class Object2 : public sc_module {
    public:
      std::array<Object, 2> obj_array;
      Object2() : obj_array <--??--> 
      {}
};
```

I need to initialize `obj_array` with `Objects`, which can't be copied and can't be moved.

I've tried a whole bunch of combinations and the one thing that compiles is:

```
class Object2:  {
    public:
      std::array<Object, 2> obj_array;
      //note the double braces on this initializer list
      Object2() : obj_array {{ {"string1", config}, {"string2", config} }} 
      {}
};
```

It works, but I see some weird behavior later on in the code: when I print out the names of the `Objects` in `obj_array`, the first one is correct `Object2.string1` but the next one is really weird `Object2.string1.string2` when it should just be `Object2.string2`).

I know a lot of people have asked pretty similar questions, but I'm trying to figure out exactly what's going on here.  It also seems to me like I've got one too many braces in that initializer list, but it won't compile otherwise.

Am using g++ 6.4.0 with flag -std=c++14

The thing is if I create another array in the body of the constructor, eg
    class Object2:  {
        public:
          std::array obj_array;
          //note the double braces on this initializer list
          Object2() : obj_array {{ {"string1", config}, {"string2", config} }} 
          {
              Obj arr[2] {{"test", config}, {"test2", config}};
          }
    };

Everything appears OK.  `arr` Object names are correct, as are their parents.

I know this is an esoteric question, but I need help understanding exactly what mechanisms are going on during my obj_array initialization.

Comment: So you say member `std::array` doesn't work and a plain local array does work. Then there is an obvious question: Did you try a plain member array?

Comment: You'd rather change constructor names from `CPU` to `Object`.

Comment: Did you check constructor implementation or even Print function? May be there is for example some static variable, which holds some state, and it results in this strange behaviour.

Comment: @NuPagadi  Updated the constructor names (my mistake).  In the constructor of Object, the first parameter is correct (the sc_module's name).  I'm thinking more and more this is a SystemC oddity in how it determines a module's parent.

Comment: Try to use `string{"string1"}` inside braces. Like `obj_array {{ {string{"string1"}, config}, {string{"string2"}, config} }}`

Answer (score 3):

The form with doubled braces is the "complete" way to initialize a `std::array`, because `std::array` is actually an aggregate struct which contains a raw C-style array.  It's essentially

```
namespace std {
    template <class T, size_t N>
    struct array {
        T __some_internal_name[N];

        // public members...
    };
}
```

So an initialization like:

```
std::array<int, 3> A{{ 2, 3, 4 }};
```

is valid because the outer `{}` are for the `std::array` struct object and the inner `{}` are for the raw C-style array it contains.

But *usually*, you don't need the doubled braces, because there's a rule that lets you omit some nested braces for an aggregate inside another aggregate.  This is why an initialization like:

```
std::array<int, 3> A{ 2, 3, 4 };
```

does the same as the above.

The rule is that as the compiler associates pieces of an initializer-list to subobjects (non-static data members of a struct/class or elements of an array) of an aggregate, if the next subobject is also an aggregate (which contains at least one subobject of its own) and the next piece of the initializer-list does not begin with the `{` token, then the subobject takes as many pieces from the initializer-list as it has direct subobjects of its own.  But if the next thing in the initializer-list begins with a `{`, it is assumed to be the complete initializer-list for that aggregate subobject.

So if you have the almost-correct code

```
Object2() : obj_array { {"string1", config}, {"string2", config} }
   {}
```

the compiler processes it something like this:

1. `obj_array` is a `std::array<Object, 2>`, which is an aggregate struct, and its initializer is a braced initializer-list, so aggregate initialization applies.
2. The first `{` is associated with the `obj_array` object.
3. `obj_array` has one subobject, of type `Object[2]`.  This type is also an aggregate type, and the next thing in the initializer-list starts with `{`, so it opens another initializer-list for initializing the `Object[2]` array.
4. The `Object[2]` contains two subobjects, both of type `Object`, which is a non-aggregate class type.
5. The first `Object` must be initialized with the next thing in the initializer-list, which is `"string1"`. But there is no valid conversion from `const char[8]` to `Object`. This is an error.

Other errors might follow after that, depending on how the compiler attempts to continue.

In short, the reason the single-brace style for the `std::array` doesn't work in your case is that since what you intended to be an `Object` initializer starts with a `{`, it gets treated as the initializer for the C-style array instead.

The double-brace solution works, or you could also specify the `Object` type to avoid starting initializer-list elements with another initializer-list:

```
Object2() : obj_array { Object{"string1", config}, Object{"string2", config} }
   {}
```

Your SystemC problem is not likely related to all this, since the double-brace style is correct and will do what you expect. It might be a detail of the `Configuration` class. (Note that your constructor takes the `Configuration` parameter "by value", meaning the object the constructor gets will be a copy of whatever you pass to it, if that matters.) I'd suggest asking a separate question with more details about that problem.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  That parts makes sense.  As far as your latter suggestion `obj_array { Object{"string1", config}, Object{"string2", config} }`  -- this fails with: `use of deleted function 'Object::Object(Object&&)'`  because it's not movable.  But I think you're right, the object hierarchy thing is probably something weird related to how SystemC determines a parent module.